# Erro em modo design no xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Estou com esse problema em meu projeto usando xamarin:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz uma busca no SOen e achei [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231060/connection-to-the-layout-renderer-failed-this-may-be-caused-by-misconfiguration), mas não resolveu. O que falta é desinstalar tudo e não tenho garantias que isso vá funcionar. No aguardo de uma ajuda.

Comment: Tem `Java 1.8` instalado? Verifique a configuração em:  `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings`